# Tinkerpop: Set Label After Creating Vertex

Tags: java, tinkerpop, tinkerpop3

Is there a way to set the `T.label` after the vertex has been created. I have tried the following:

```
Vertex v = graph.addVertex();
v.property(T.label.name(), "test");
```

But when I try the following traversal:

```
graph.traversal().V().hasLabel("test").next
```

I get

```
org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.traversal.util.FastNoSuchElementException
```

Is there something special about `T.label` that limits it to being set at the step of constructing the vertex ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, labels cannot be changed. If you need this type of functionality, you should use a vertex property instead.

From the TinkerPop [documentation](http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/reference/#_the_graph_structure): "NOTE: In TinkerPop3, vertices are allowed a single immutable string label (similar to an edge label). This functionality did not exist in TinkerPop2. Likewise, element id’s are immutable as they were in TinkerPop2."